# casting a tiny int from SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to sql to populate a list of objects. One of the fields I'm interested in is stored as a tinyint. How should I declare this property type in my object definition? As a Short? Byte? Int16?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It will be a byte. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) is a complete list.

Comment: For ones who use **MySQL**, none of them works. In my case `short` worked well.

Answer (score 3):

It's a byte.

[MSDN SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Byte

[some extra characters..]

Answer (score 1):

It's an unsigned byte, so `Byte`.

Answer (score 0):

If your's tinyint is tinyint(1) then you can cast it to bool.